# Как научить нейросеть выделять определенные слова и на основе их давать ответ

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Хочу написать нейросеть для защиты от телефонных мошенников. Идея такая, программа распознает голос, выделяет определенные слова и если их становится слишком много, то выдает предупреждение. Распознавание голоса я реализовал. Но не могу понять как реализовать выделение слов. Подскажите какие библиотеки можно для этого использовать. это мой первый опыт для проекта в ВУЗе